Use Python's logging to overwriting previous console line
I want to use Python's logging library to overwrite the previous console line. It should display ... on the console while the process is running, then overwrite it with OK once the process completes, as shown in this Python code.
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(f'Progress: {i+1}/10 ...', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'\rProgress: {i+1}/10  OK')


I want to achieve the same result using the logging library, but my current solution feels too verbose and un-pythonic. Does anyone have a better approach? Thanks!
import logging
import sys
import time

class OverwriteStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, stream, overwrite=False):
        super().__init__(stream)
        self.overwrite = overwrite

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        stream = self.stream
        if self.overwrite:
            stream.write('\r' + msg)
        else:
            stream.write(msg)
        stream.flush()

def create_logger(name, overwrite=False):
    handler = OverwriteStreamHandler(sys.stdout, overwrite=overwrite)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

logger1 = create_logger('logger1')
logger2 = create_logger('logger2', overwrite=True)

for i in range(10):
    logger1.info(f'Progress: {i+1}/10 ...')
    time.sleep(1)
    logger2.info(f'Progress: {i+1}/10  Ok\n')


Another alternative is to use ANSI escape codes.  There are codes to move the cursor up a line.

Seems fine to me. From what I understand, logging's focus isn't on interacting with a terminal, so you need to write a lot of boilerplate to make it work. There are probably little things you could improve, but the broad strokes look good to me.

There are 2 options:

Add a handler with empty terminator and manually add the line terminator to each message.
Create an additional logger with terminator='\r' configured at the handler.

In both cases all line lengths must be of the longest message to avoid output garbage. Pad with spaces if needed.
Option 1
import logging
import time

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def get_logger(name, formatter, terminator='\n'):
    lggr = logging.getLogger(name)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.terminator = terminator

    lggr.addHandler(ch)
    lggr.propagate = False
    return ch, lggr

ch1, logger1 = get_logger("SO_log1", formatter, terminator='')

logger1.info('Started\n')


for i in range(10):
    msg = f'Progress: {i+1:>2}/10 {"..."}\r'
    logger1.info(msg)
    time.sleep(0.21)
    msg = f'Progress: {i+1:>2}/10 {"Ok":>3}\r'
    if i == 10:
        msg += "\n"
    logger1.info(msg)
    # additional delay to get a chance to see the Ok msg
    time.sleep(0.21)

logger1.info('\n')

Output where date and last 9 characters of message will alternate
2024-12-18 23:44:32,535 - SO_log1 - INFO - Started
2024-12-18 23:44:34,638 - SO_log1 - INFO - Progress: 10/10  Ok

Option 2
Use 2 loggers and set line terminator on the second handler
import logging
import time

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def get_logger(name, formatter, terminator='\n'):
    lggr = logging.getLogger(name)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.terminator = terminator

    lggr.addHandler(ch)
    lggr.propagate = False
    return ch, lggr

ch1, logger1 = get_logger("SO_log1", formatter)
ch2, logger2 = get_logger("SO_log2", formatter, terminator='\r')

logger1.info('Started opt 2')

for i in range(10):
    msg = f'Progress: {i+1:>2}/10 {"..."}'
    logger2.info(msg)
    time.sleep(0.21)
    msg = f'Progress: {i+1:>2}/10 {"Ok":>3}'
    #logger2.info(msg)

    if i < 10:
        logger2.info(msg)
    else:
        logger1.info(msg)
    time.sleep(0.21)

logger1.info("\n")

Output 2
2024-12-19 00:03:38,262 - SO_log1 - INFO - Started opt 2
2024-12-19 00:03:42,467 - SO_log1 - INFO - Progress: 10/10  Ok


